# NodeJS: Can't kill spawn of gulp process

Tags: node.js, process, spawn

I'd like to restart `gulp` on certain changes. That can be easily done by placing the following within the `gulpfile`

```
spawn('gulp', [], { stdio: 'inherit'});
```

However, once `gulp` restarts in this way, the process is no longer killed properly with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> via the terminal. If I start `gulp` via terminal, I can capture a <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> signal, but can't if `gulp` was started via the `spawn` in `gulpfile`. How can I capture 'SIGINT' for the spawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here's the full story to anyone who might encounter the issue. From what I have been reading, whenever you want to restart gulp from within gulp you simply use:

```
spawn('gulp', [], { stdio: 'inherit'});
process.exit();
```

I didn't mention `process.exit()` in my question as I didn't expect it to affect the usage of <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. Indeed it was, as my server was an ExpressJS one, whenever I'd use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> after gulp restarted from within itself, I would get the port still in use error (`Error: listen EADDRINUSE`). Obviously, all node processes wasn't being closed. Once I removed the line `process.exit()` from my code, I was able to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and successfully close all processes. Below is the useful bit of code in the gulpfile and output in terminal that is related to this issue.

```
// gulpfile.js
gulp.task('restart', function() {
  server.close();
  spawn('gulp', [], { stdio: 'inherit'});
  process.exit(); // this line needs to be removed
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('Successfully closed ' + process.pid));
    process.exit(1);
  }, 500);
});

// Console results:
^C[20:12:12] Successfully closed 67160
[20:12:12] Successfully closed 67151
```